# inheritance and polymorphism for class and its member at the same time (shared_ptr, C++11)

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, c++11, polymorphism

I am playing around with the following structure of classes which use std::shared_ptr (C++11):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

//class Member is given by a 3rd party library, CAN'T modify its structure!
class Member {//no instance of this class allowed
   public:
     Member() {};//should never be called
     virtual ~Member() = 0;//pure virtual distructor;
     virtual void foo() {
       std::cout<<"Member"<<std::endl;
     }
};
Member::~Member() {} //need to define destructor because of child classes 

class ChildMember : public Member {
  public:
     ChildMember() {};
     virtual void foo() {
         std::cout<<"Child Member"<<std::endl;
     }

     virtual void foo2() {
        std::cout<<"unique foo in child"<<std::endl;
     }
};

class Base {
   public:
     Base() {};

   virtual
   std::shared_ptr< Member >
   get_var() {return var;}

   virtual void 
   set_var ( std::shared_ptr< Member > v) { var = v;}

   std::shared_ptr< Member > var;
};


class ChildBase : public Base {
  public:
     ChildBase() {
        //var = std::make_shared<ChildMember>();
     };

  virtual
  std::shared_ptr< ChildMember >
  get_var() {return var;} //(2) : try to comment

  virtual void 
  set_var ( std::shared_ptr< ChildMember > v) { var = v;}

  std::shared_ptr< ChildMember > var;
};

void func(std::shared_ptr<Base> b) {
    b->get_var()->foo();// process input using polymorphism
}

int main() 
{
    std::shared_ptr<ChildBase> cb( std::make_shared<ChildBase>());
    cb->set_var (std::make_shared<ChildMember>() );
    cb->get_var()->foo2();//(3) want to use unique functions of ChildBase;
    cb->var->foo2();      //can access directly as well;
    //cb->var = std::make_shared<ChildMember>();
    func(cb);
}
```

What i try to do is design two classes (`Base` and `ChildBase`) where each one has its own member `Member` / `ChildMember`. After full usage of `ChildBase` object and its member object of type `ChildMember`, i pass it to a function `func` which receives `Base` and should, using **polymorphism** call the proper `foo` of a member `var`.

Problems:
**(1)**
In the variant in the above, compiler complains that:

```
 overriding 'virtual std::shared_ptr<Member> Base::get_var()'
     get_var() {return var;}`
```

**(2)**
If i comment-out `ChildBase` implementation of `get_var`, this function is treated as `Base` and thus returns a pointer to `Member` which does not have `foo2`.

**(3)**
I can also comment out `cb->get_var()->foo2()` . The whole things compiles, but it seems it does not call `ChildMember::foo()` as there is no output `Child Member`;

Something is (hopefully) slightly messed up but i don't see what. Could you guys please help to correct it?

**EDIT1**:

based on Abhijit Kadam answer, the following code fully compiles:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Member {//no instance of this class allowed
   public:
     Member() {};
     virtual ~Member() = 0;//pure virtual distructor;
     virtual void foo() {
       std::cout<<"Member"<<std::endl;
     }
};
Member::~Member() {} //need to define destructor for child classes 

class ChildMember : public Member {
  public:
     ChildMember() {};
     virtual void foo() {
        std::cout<<"Child Member"<<std::endl;
     }

     void foo2() {
        std::cout<<"unique foo in child"<<std::endl;
     }
};

class Base {
   public:
     Base() {};

     std::shared_ptr< Member >
     get_var() {return var;}

     void set_var ( std::shared_ptr< Member > v) { var = v;}

     std::shared_ptr< Member > var;
};


class ChildBase : public Base {
  public:
     ChildBase() {
       //var = std::make_shared<ChildMember>();
     };  

     std::shared_ptr< ChildMember > var;
};

void func(std::shared_ptr<Base> b) {
    b->get_var()->foo();// process input using polymorphism
}

 void func_vec( std::vector< 
              std::shared_ptr<Base>
           > vec) {
     for (unsigned int i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
          vec[i]->get_var()->foo();
  }

int main() 
{
   std::shared_ptr<ChildBase> cb( std::make_shared<ChildBase>());
   cb->set_var (std::make_shared<ChildMember>() );

   func(cb);

   std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Base>> vec;
   vec.push_back(cb);
   func_vec(vec);

   cb->var->foo2();

   /*std::shared_ptr<ChildMember> ptr(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<ChildMember>(cb->get_var()) );
   if (ptr) {
      ptr->foo2();
   } */
}
```

**EDIT2**
added an answer below.

Comment: What you want needs raw pointers or references (see ForEveR's answer). Also, your function declarations (on 3 lines) is horrible (at least for me).

Comment: I believe get_var and set_var should not be virtual and should be there in base class only. Also if the Member and ChildMember inheritance follow proper "is a relationship" then foo2 should be virtual in the Member class or should not be in either of the class.

Comment: @AbhijitKadam that was actually my goal to have a derived class with something in addition to the base class, namely `foo2`.

Comment: If that is something that cannot be avoided then can use dynamic cast to check if the pointer is of type `ChildMember`. This would be relatively safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the return types of overriding functions cannot differ I would have use dynamic cast to implement the solution. Hence no need to have virtual functions for `get_var and set_var'. Also no need for foo2 to be virtual unless the class would be further derived by some other class.

```
int main() 
{
    std::shared_ptr<ChildBase> cb( std::make_shared<ChildBase>());
    cb->set_var (std::make_shared<ChildMember>() );

    shared_ptr<ChildMember> ptr(dynamic_pointer_cast<ChildMember>(cb->get_var()) );
    if (ptr) {
        ptr->foo2();
    } 
}

class Member {//no instance of this class allowed
   public:
     Member() {};
     virtual ~Member() = 0;//pure virtual distructor;
     virtual void foo() {
       std::cout<<"Member"<<std::endl;
     }
};
Member::~Member() {} //need to define destructor for child classes 

class ChildMember : public Member {
  public:
     ChildMember() {};
     virtual void foo() {
         std::cout<<"Child Member"<<std::endl;
     }

     void foo2() {
        std::cout<<"unique foo in child"<<std::endl;
     }
};

class Base {
   public:
     Base() {};

   std::shared_ptr< Member >
   get_var() {return var;}

   void set_var ( std::shared_ptr< Member > v) { var = v;}

   std::shared_ptr< Member > var;
};


class ChildBase : public Base {
  public:
     ChildBase() {
        //var = std::make_shared<ChildMember>();
     };  

  std::shared_ptr< ChildMember > var;
};

void func(std::shared_ptr<Base> b) {
    b->get_var()->foo();// process input using polymorphism
}
```

Comment: thanks, i added a slightly modified version of your answer to the post

Comment: I added another solution to the post, would love to hear your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
virtual
std::shared_ptr< Member >
get_var() {return var;}

virtual
std::shared_ptr< ChildMember >
get_var() {return var;} //(2) : try to comment
```

It's wrong overriding.
n3337 10.3/7

> The return type of an overriding function shall be either identical to the return type of the overridden
> function or covariant with the classes of the functions. If a function D::f overrides a function B::f, the
> return types of the functions are covariant if they satisfy the following criteria:
>
> — both are pointers to classes, both are lvalue references to classes, or both are rvalue references to
> classes
>
> — the class in the return type of B::f is the same class as the class in the return type of D::f, or is an
> unambiguous and accessible direct or indirect base class of the class in the return type of D::f
>
> — both pointers or references have the same cv-qualification and the class type in the return type of D::f
> has the same cv-qualification as or less cv-qualification than the class type in the return type of B::f.

All conditions fails in your case. You can use raw-pointers, or references for this, something like http://liveworkspace.org/code/4eQWBI$1
But I think you should rewrite your interface and not use `foo2`, if it's not virtual.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, see this modified and annotated version of your code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Member {//no instance of this class allowed
public:
    Member() {};
    virtual ~Member() = 0;//pure virtual distructor;
    virtual void foo() {
        std::cout<<"Member"<<std::endl;
    }
};
Member::~Member() {} //need to define destructor for child classes 

class ChildMember : public Member {
public:
    ChildMember() {};
    virtual void foo() {
        std::cout<<"Child Member"<<std::endl;
    }

    virtual void foo2() {
        std::cout<<"unique foo in child"<<std::endl;
    }
};

class Base {
public:
    Base() {};

    // maybe you should have a virtual dtor here
    virtual ~Base();

    // note: NOT virtual
    std::shared_ptr< Member >
    get_var() {return var;}

    // also NOT virtual
    void set_var ( std::shared_ptr< Member > v) { var = v;}

    std::shared_ptr< Member > var;
};


class ChildBase : public Base {
public:
    ChildBase() {
        //var = std::make_shared<ChildMember>();
    };

    // non-virtual version which casts var to the correct type
    std::shared_ptr< ChildMember >
    get_var() {return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<ChildMember>(var);}

    // note: no var here, use the one from Base
};

void func(std::shared_ptr<Base> b) {
    b->get_var()->foo();// process input using polymorphism
}

int main() 
{
    std::shared_ptr<ChildBase> cb( std::make_shared<ChildBase>());
    cb->set_var (std::make_shared<ChildMember>() );
    cb->get_var()->foo2();//(3) want to use unique functions of ChildBase;

    // This can't work:
    //cb->var->foo2();      //can access directly as well;

    //cb->var = std::make_shared<ChildMember>();
    func(cb);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i though the answer of Abhijit Kadam is a little bit better since it can be slightly modified to use no casting at all.

Comment: @Denis: OK, just one warning: `ChildBase` now contains two `var`s, the one from `ChildBase` and the one from `Base`. That's bloating the object size (which my solution avoids) and you might run into trouble because of one `var` being set and the other one being empty. I prefer not to have this kind of ambiguity in my code, but if it works for your use-case, I guess it's OK.

Comment: I added another solution to the post, what do you think?

Comment: @Denis That'll work as long as you only derive one level deep from `Base`, so it's not as scalable as mine, but it'll safe you from the `dynamic_cast`, which is a plus. Also, you should really add a virtual dtor to `Base`.

Comment: it actually works for more than 1 lvl of inheritance, look the answer below.

Comment: @Denis Except that now you (again) have two `shared_ptr`s in `ChildChildBase`, this time called `var` and `var2` and you are back to the warning above. But OK, I guess you'll have to collect your own experience with this kind of design :)

Answer (score 0):

`shared_ptr` is *not* a pointer, so covariance doesn't apply.

Typically, I'm sceptical about the use of covariance anyway.  I
generally find it cleaner for the derived class to not change
the return types, and to provide a new function if it needs to
return a pointer to a derived function.  In your case, I'd say
that this is essential, since you actually have two pointers
(which could end up pointing to different objects).

Answer (score 0):

after a while, i though the following code might be a good solution:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Member {//no instance of this class allowed
   public:
     Member() {};
     virtual ~Member() = 0;//pure virtual distructor;
     virtual void foo() {
       std::cout<<"Member"<<std::endl;
     }
};
Member::~Member() {} //need to define destructor for child classes 

class ChildMember1 : public Member {
  public:
     ChildMember1() {};
     virtual void foo() {
        std::cout<<"Child Member 1"<<std::endl;
     }

     void foo1() {
        std::cout<<"unique foo in child 1"<<std::endl;
     }
};

class ChildMember2 : public Member {
  public:
     ChildMember2() {};
     virtual void foo() {
        std::cout<<"Child Member 2"<<std::endl;
     }
};

class ChildChildMember2 : public ChildMember2 {
   public:
      ChildChildMember2() {};
      virtual void foo() {
         std::cout<<"Child-Child Member 2"<<std::endl;
      }
};

class Base {
   public:
     Base() {};
     virtual
     ~Base() {};

     virtual
     std::shared_ptr< Member >
     get_var() = 0; //purely abstract class

};

class ChildBase1 : public Base {
  public:
     ChildBase1() {
       var = std::make_shared<ChildMember1>();
     };

     virtual
     std::shared_ptr< Member >
     get_var() {return var;}

     std::shared_ptr< ChildMember1 > var;
};

class ChildChildBase : public ChildBase1 {
   public:
      ChildChildBase() {
         var2 = std::make_shared< ChildChildMember2>();
      }

   virtual
   std::shared_ptr< Member >
   get_var() { return var2; }

   std::shared_ptr< ChildChildMember2 > var2;
};


class ChildBase2 : public Base {
  public:
     ChildBase2() {
       var = std::make_shared<ChildMember2>();
     };  

     virtual
     std::shared_ptr< Member >
     get_var() {return var;}

     std::shared_ptr< ChildMember2 > var;
};

void func(std::shared_ptr<Base> b) {
    b->get_var()->foo();// process input using polymorphism
}

int main() 
{
   std::shared_ptr<ChildBase1> cb1( std::make_shared<ChildBase1>());
   cb1->var->foo1();
   func(cb1);

   std::shared_ptr<ChildBase2> cb2( std::make_shared<ChildBase2>());
   func(cb2);

   std::shared_ptr<ChildChildBase> ccb( std::make_shared<ChildChildBase>());
   func(ccb);

}
```

I think it achieves what i was after without parallel inheritance or dynamic casting. It also has more than 1 lvl of inheritance.

The output is:

```
unique foo in child 1
Child Member 1
Child Member 2
Child-Child Member 2
```